# pyvmomi: Retrieving "Transport" information

Tags: api, vsphere, esxi, pyvmomi

I am trying to print out Transport Details (From the vCenter -  Host > Storage Devices > Device Details > Transport > SAS (for example) using pyvmomi.

This is the API I have been using as a reference:
https://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.MultipathInfo.Path.html

```
HostMultiPathInfoLuns = host.config.storageDevice.multipathInfo.lun
        for lun in HostMultiPathInfoLuns:
            for path in lun.path:
                print(path.transport)
```

This prints out the following:

```
(vim.host.SerialAttachedTargetTransport) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) []
}
(vim.host.SerialAttachedTargetTransport) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) []
}
```

I am interested in retrieving something like this:
(Run the esxcli storage core path list command to generate a list of all LUN paths currently connected to the ESXi host.)

```
fc.5001438005685fb5:5001438005685fb4-fc.50060160c46036df:50060167446036df-naa.6006016094602800e07ff528b73ae011
UID: fc.5001438005685fb5:5001438005685fb4-fc.50060160c46036df:50060167446036df-naa.6006016094602800e07ff528b73ae011
Runtime Name: vmhba0:C0:T0:L23
Device: naa.6006016094602800e07ff528b73ae011
Device Display Name: DGC Fibre Channel Disk ( naa.6006016094602800e07ff528b73ae011)
Adapter: vmhba0
Channel: 0
Target: 0
LUN: 23
Plugin: NMP
State: active
Transport: fc
Adapter Identifier: fc.5001438005685fb5:5001438005685fb4
Target Identifier: fc.50060160c46036df:50060167446036df
Adapter Transport Details: WWNN:-43-WWPN: 50:01:43:80:05:68:5f:b4
Target Transport Details: WWNN:-45-WWPN: 50:06:01:67:44:60:36:d
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll likely want to access the individual attributes of the lun path that are of interest to you.  Instead of just doing `print(path.transport)`, try something like `print(path.transport.address)` and `print(path.transport.iScsiName)`.  I only see three attributes on that object in my debugger, they are address, iScsiName, and iScsiAlias

Comment: I didn't see any transport information , @v dev did you get any further info on this ?